# Модификации алгоритма Ахо-Корасика

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Ознакамливаясь с алгоритмом Ахо-Корасик, мне стал не понятен раздел ["Нахождение кратчайшей строки, содержащей вхождения одновременно всех образцов"](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/aho_corasick)(второй с конца), каким образом происходит "переход по ребру автомата в другую вершину с соответствующим изменением маски", так же в следующем пункте "Нахождение лексикографически наименьшей строки длины L, содержащей данные образцы в сумме k раз", тоже не понятно как именно происходит переход между состояниями. Хотелось бы увидеть реализацию решения данных проблем.

Comment: Алгоритм Ахо - Корасик мудреный, но он просто использует бор и суффиксные ссылки, у нас есть she он сошлется на состояния he и e. На практике проще использовать алгоритм Рабина Карпа или Кнута — Морриса — Пратта. Они реализуются легче.